# Logging separate from CherryPy logger

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy application and enabled logging (access and app files).

```
conf = {'/':
    {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': WEB_ROOT,
        'tools.staticdir.index': 'debug_registers2.html',
        'log.access_file': ACCESS_LOG,
        'log.error_file': APP_LOG,
    }
}
```

Besides the default CherryPy log data, I also use statements like:

```
cherrypy.log("My text here")
```

Now I need to create a 3rd log file, that I will pass some other data to.
If I do:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=SPI_LOG,level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the SPI log file')
```

My CherryPy log data also goes into the "SPI_LOG" file.

How can I keep the two separate?

Answer (score 1):

By default, cherrypy has the following logging structure:

- `"cherrypy.error"` logger, with it's own handler.
- `"cherrypy.access"` logger, with it's own handler.
- `"cherrypy"` logger, that is parent from the two first ones, and receive their logs, but doesn't have any handler associated.
- And the ever present `"root"` logger, which is parent from the `"cherrypy"` logger, with no handler associated.

1)  So with this configuration, CherryPy writes logs to the error and access logs. This logs are captured and displayed by their respective handlers. If you use `cherrypy.log()` you will send a log from `"cherrypy.error"` .

All logs are also send up to `"cherrypy"` and then `"root"` logger but it has no effect as they have no handlers.

2) After that if you use `logging.error()` from your app, a handler is created for the root log, and logs send to it. This root handler will thus display your logs AND the cherrypy logs. Your logs will appear one time, and cherrypy logs will appear two times, one through their own handler, and then through the root handler when the message goes up to it. You can see that the handlers are different because cherrypy handlers are customised (time stamp) and the auto root handler has another format.

3) If you create a logger for your application and log through it,

```
local_logger=logging.getLogger("my logger")
```

messages will not appear because it hasn't any handler yet, then message is passed to the root logger (also parent of "my logger") that has neither any handler associated.

4) If you create a logger for your app AND invoke `logging.basicConfig()`, it will create a handler for the root logger, and you will be in the same situation as 2)

5) finally if you create a logger for your application

```
local_logger=logging.getLogger("my logger")
```

and then create a handler for it

```
local_logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Then your logs to it will be displayed through it's handler, then send up to root logger, along with the already handled cherrypy logs, but at this level none of them will be displayed a second time because root logger still has no handler associated to it! That's is what you want. To use file instead of console output, just choose another class of handler.

This took me forever to figure out how all of this work, and struggled with cherrypy double logs and mine not being displayed, and all in diferent formats and all! I found it nowhere clearly explained so I hope this helps!

Comment: Just set `logging.getLogger("cherrypy").propagate = False` at the top of the file to never see cherrypy logs on screen. 

For a demo, see: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1566#issuecomment-296993493

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the root logger (which, as a parent of CP's logger, also receives all its messages). Create a child with `logging.getLogger('myapp')`. And instead of calling `basicConfig()` you'll have to separately `setLevel()` and create, configure, and attach `FileHandler` and `Formatter`.